# Magento Google captcha is not loading the first time unless we do a browser hard reload

Tags: magento2, captcha, google, recaptcha

Magento 2 Google captcha is not loading the first time on the login page unless we do a browser hard reload.

When we do a hard reload of the browser, the captcha loads. Next time even if we do a normal reload the captcha